# Using type defined inside templated type

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, using

Is there any nice way to do the following?

```cpp
                                 /* vvv */
template<typename Wrapper> using T = typename Wrapper::type
T f(const T &a, const T &b) { 
    return a + b; 
}
```

where `Wrapper` is some class which contains (several) types defined inside of it.

I can do the following, but I don't like this approach as it makes the function have several templated types (and also does not have the exact same meaning):

```cpp
template<typename Wrapper, typename T = typename Wrapper::type>
T f(..)
```

---

I want to do this purely to reduce boilerplate of typing `typename Wrapper::type` in the function declaration. If there is a better way to do this, please let me know.

*Note:* in my project the `Wrapper` type needs to satisfy some concept, which also requires having the type `type` defined inside the type `Wrapper`.

---

If it may help, here is my use case. I am (attempting) to write a linear algebra library. In this scenario, in order to create objects such as vectors or matrices, we need to supply a field **F**, which must satisfy:

- F is over some elementary type T (available by e.g., `F::type`)
- F is supplied with two operations `OpAdd` and `OpMul`, both of which can operate on `T`.

Defining this using concepts is simple, however this adds some clutter, such as my example above.

Comment: People normally just use `T` as the template parameter because this way prevents deduction.  It might help to see more of your use case.

Comment: You're probably able to reduce the number of occurances of `T` by one by using `auto` as return type... As for the remaining part of the problem: You may be able to reduce the length of the code by a minimal amount using a type alias: `template<class Wrapper> using Type = typename Wrapper::type; ... template<typename Wrapper> auto f(const Type<Wrapper> &a, ...)`

Comment: @fabian Using `auto` creates a bunch more functions, such as `f(X, Y)` (assuming `X` and `Y` can be added).

Comment: @talbi the only place I wanted to suggest adding `auto` is as return type of the function; this would only result in a single function per wrapper, but it may not work in 100% of the cases(e.g. if `Wrapper::type` is `char`).

Comment: Take in count that if `T` is the type of an argument (as in your first example), `T` is deduced from the argument, so `template<typename Wrapper, typename T = typename Wrapper::type>` simply doesn't works. To avoid this problem you have to add a check that `std::is_same<T, typename Wrapper::type`, as in 273K's answer (but this disable the function calling it with the wrong type, that can o cannot be what do you want) or using the David G's solution, that disable the type deduction for `T` from the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know what the type will be? If so you can supply the template argument:

```
template<class T>
using inner = typename T::type;

template<class T>
inner<T> f(inner<T> const& a, inner<T> const& b);

// ...
f<X>(y, y);
```

Comment: Note that `auto` may not result in the exact same signature as the function in the question, e.g. if `Wrapper::type` is `char`...

Answer (score 0):

In requested circumstances, what you don't like is the only solution

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename Wrapper,
         typename T = typename Wrapper::type,
         typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, typename Wrapper::type>::value>::type* = nullptr>
T f(const T &a, const T &b) { 
    return a + b; 
}

struct S {
  typedef long type;
};

int main() {
  f<S>(0L, 0L);   // ok
  // f<S>(0, 0);  // failure

  // If the second type is set explicitly 
  f<S, long>(0L, 0L);    // ok
  f<S, long>(0, 0);      // ok
  // f<S, int>(0L, 0L);  // failure
  // f<S, int>(0, 0);    // failure
}
```

This is a better solution than one with `inner<T>`, because `f<S>(0, 0)` will not fail with `inner<T>` - the exact `long` is required but `int` is passed.

Comment: I don't think that this is the best solution (assuming typing isn't a problem); this creates more functions then I'd like to define - such as `f<Wrapper<long>, int>`

Comment: BTW you can use `std::enable_if` for preventing other types `T` that are not `Wrapper::type`.